# formula help to converting and select the value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]

```
if (sqlDataReader1["ProductPromotion"].ToString() != null)
  {

}
```

i want to based on the total price and selling price to calculate the discount % and display on ddl. my ddl have a value.

how to do this formula?
inside the datareader i can do,

```
 string promotion = sqlDataReader1["ProductPromotion"].ToString();
string sellPrice = sqlDataReader1["ProductSalesPrice"].ToString();

the formula is like this
112.40 / 140.50 = Ans1
1-Ans1 = Ans2
Ans2 *100 =20

112.40/140.50 =0.8
1 - 0.8=0.2
0.2*100 =20

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDis" runat="server" Width="80px" onchange="CalculateCost();">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">0%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="15">15%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="20">20%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="25">25%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="30">30%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="35">35%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="40">40%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="45">45%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="50">50%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="55">55%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="60">60%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="65">65%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="70">70%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="75">75%</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="80">80%</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: your selling price is 140. with 0% discount how do you get 112 ?

Comment: i use scripting to convert var total = selPrice - (selPrice * (parseInt(discount.replace("%", "")) / 100));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the percentage in dropdown,

Append "%" to that 20 and assign it to the model.

and,

```
Html.DropdownList(m=>model.percentage,new SelectList(yourddlsource(),**Model.percentage**)) 
//The last mentioned value is dropdown's selected value(**3rd one**)
```

load the view with the model and it will appear 20%.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get 20 by using this formula. How to select the value on ddl based on the total?

```
double total = Convert.ToDouble(promotion) / Convert.ToDouble(sellPrice);
total = 1 - total;
total = total * 100;
 ddlDis.Items.FindByValue(total); // error with this 2 line
 ddlDis.Items[total].Selected = true;
```